# Answering RMM emails on SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, reply-mail-management

When customers reply to any of our promo emails or our ship confirmations, the email address that auto populates for our response looks like this: blablabla.hotmail.com@companyname.com

The reps answer emails really quickly and often forget to change the email to the correct format.

Is it possible to fix this, in a way that just customer email auto-populate when reps are responding back to customers?

Comment: Have you looked at https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_create_dynamic_rmm_configuration.htm&type=5 for setting up dynamic reply mail management?

Comment: Hi @thechrishaddad! Yes, but I didn't tryied to implement. I'm wondering if this will affect the the 'Send to' address when the Rep clicks to reply a customer question, for example. I know that it is possible to send 'on behalf' of the Rep team, but the issue here is the 'Send to' email.